# Angular 2 with Material Design - Responsive behaviour not working?

Tags: angular, styles, angular-material2

I'am using Angular Material with Angular2. The code contains `md-card`, `md-content`, `md-input-container`and some other Material design directives.

In the start page (app.component) I'am using `md-tab-group` with 3 tabs. In one of them the form is being loaded... it works as expected. My issue is then how to make the form-width around 33% and centered but keep the responsive behaviour by mobile devices.

I did few CSS workarounds with DIVs and other CSS definitions, and was able to change the Width to 33% and center it, but I loose the responsive behaviour of the page and therefore none of my CSS definitions did help (by iPhone 6 portrait, the form is too small.. takes 100% of 33% of its wrapper)

I don't want to add media queries because I would like to use the Built-In Material Design responsive features.

login.component:

```
<md-card>
    <form #form="ngForm" method="POST">
        <div>
            <md-input-container>
                <md-placeholder>
                    <md-icon mdPrefix>mail</md-icon> Email
                </md-placeholder>
                <br>
                <input mdInput name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" #inputMail required>
                <md-error>Email is required</md-error>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div>
            <md-input-container>
                <md-placeholder>
                    <md-icon  mdPrefix>lock_outline</md-icon> password
                </md-placeholder>
                <br>
                <input mdInput type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="xxx" #inputPass required="">
                <md-error>Password is required</md-error>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="button-row">
            <button type="submit" class="submit" md-button (click)="loginCheck(inputMail.value, inputPass.value)">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</md-card>
```

app.component:

```
<md-tab-group flex>
    <md-tab label="Login">
        <div id="page-padding">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet> //loading login form
        </div>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Sign Up">
        <br><br>
        <div id="page-padding">
            <router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="How To">
        <router-outlet name="howto"></router-outlet>
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>

<div layout-align="center center">
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
    </div>
</div>
```

Any Idea how to fix this please? Should I install (using npm) and/or import any further packages for responsive behaviour?

Comment: Include a viewport-meta-tag like <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> to tell the brower that your site is responsive and should be rendered using correct CSS pixel scaling.

Comment: @RahulSingh: I'am using it already: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure you can fix your issues if you use Angular Flex Layout

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

It automatically handles media query breaks and other responsive issues. It works well in conjunction with Angular Material

Comment: I tried it before and it didn't give me the expected result. and the available version on npm registry is: 2.0.0-beta.8 where I'am not sure that it would work correctly. Here is what I get when running the npm outdated command: 

Package                     Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
`flex-layout-srcs       2.0.0-beta.8     git     git  projectName`

Comment: @k.vincent It will still work with Angular 4 versions `2.0.0-beta.8` and above -> [More info](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)

Comment: @Edric: Sure, I'll give it a try once again... maybe I did miss something in  my code

Comment: @k.vincent Make sure you import `FlexLayoutModule` to your `@NgModule` (under `imports`).

Comment: @Edric: Yes, I'am aware about this. Has been added, but didn't help. Followed even this example: [Basic usage](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGewVG). It's still taking the whole browser width.

Comment: @k.vincent The example you linked to doesn't show how to use it! (That's for AngularJS Material!)

Answer (score 1):

Simply install `@angular/flex-layout` via npm:

```bash
npm install --save @angular/flex-layout@latest
```

Then import the module in your `app.module.ts`:

```ts
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/material';
// ...
@NgModule([
    imports: [
        FlexLayoutModule,
        // ...
    ]
])
export class AppModule {}
```

To use `flex`, add an attribute `fxFlex` to the part where you want to put it:

```html
<md-tab-group fxFlex>
<md-tab label="Login">
    <div class="page-padding">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet> <!--loading login form-->
    </div>
</md-tab>
<md-tab label="Sign Up">
    <br><br>
    <div class="page-padding">
        <router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</md-tab>
<md-tab label="How To">
    <router-outlet name="howto"></router-outlet>
</md-tab>
```

Check out the [`@angular/flex-layout` wiki](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki) for more info, more attributes and what they do.

**Notes:**

1. Please use a unique id for each tab's padding or use `class` instead.
2. Please DON'T mix `material-design-lite` and `angularjs-material` together!

   - For example, replace `layout-align` with `fxLayoutAlign` and `flex` with `fxFlex`.

Comment: Have done all these steps... still to figure out how it exactly should be used in the HTML markup - view

Comment: @k.vincent Updated the answer to show how to place in markup.